# Hyperlink To Web Form With File Pre-Attached

Tags: javascript, php, html, rest

**I want to give the user a link to click which will POST a file (stored on my server) to a web form on another website (EDIT: and redirect the user to the other website).**

Here is an example of how the HTML might look:

```
<form action="forward_uploaded_file.php">
   Uploaded File: <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" value="upload_file.dat"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

However, you can't set the value of *input type="file"* for security reasons.

Is there some alternative which will allow me to do what I want?

I'm using PHP, Javascript, HTML.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have control over the destination website?

Comment: If you're trying to upload a file that's stored on the server, it can't be done by the client. Why don't you use PHP `curl` to send it from a script on the server?

Comment: I think you could do it using html5's file api, by first downloading the file underwater and then adding it to the post.

Comment: I do not have control over the destination website.

I want to redirect the user to the other website, not simply download the contents of it. I think that I need to use something like Header instead of CURL, but I couldn't find an example of how to do that.

Comment: As @Barmar pointed out, if you have the file on your server, you don't have a way for the client to send it to this third party website.  The best you can probably do is to provide the file as a download to the client and then have the client place that file into the file upload dialog in a form targeted to the third party site.

Answer (score 0):

Hope i understood this question correctly.

1. User is on website A.
2. User clicks Button for sending a File to website B.
3. That click triggers a PHP script on website A.
4. That PHP script sends the file (already stored on website a) via POST request to website B.

My answer is: use cURL.

```
$post = array('extra_info' => 'extra_info',
              'file_contents'=> realpath($file_name_with_full_path));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url_websiteB);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Number 4 of your list is slightly different from what I'm trying to do:

1.User is on website A.
2.User clicks Button for sending a File to website B.
3.That click triggers a script on website A.
4.That script sends the file (already stored on website a) via POST request AND REDIRECTS THE USER to website B.

Comment: use javascript event on the button click and do a window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); or do the redirect to B inside the php script (header('Location: '.$newURL);).

Comment: I like the way you are thinking. However website A creates the file (based off of a different file submitted by the user). Since the file isn't submitted by the user, replacing the window location won't get the file to website B.

I think that the redirecting the user to the other website using PHP is what I need to do. I think that I have to convert the file to binary and then specify it using the Header command. I'm not sure how to do that though.

Comment: clicking the button will trigger the php script, sending the file from a to b. so you might simply place a header redirection at the end of that file. an alternative would be to use an AJAX GET request to the PHP script (which sends the file) and set a diffent window.location. this is not a file conversion problem.